# issue with Jenkins and the build cache for Android

Tags: android, caching, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build an Android project.
The problem I have is that unless I disable the cache Jenkins gives me several errors like for example:

> 12:31:15 AAPT: \?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.android\build-cache\34562456245625\output\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_left_mtrl_dark.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

I can't disable the cache because I would have to do it in the `gradle.properties` file that is shared on git.

I do not want to use the cache on Jenkins because I want to be sure that the builds always run from scratch.

What's the best practice in this case? Should I leave the cache on or off?
If I need to turn it off how can I do it without stopping the cache while building on the developers' machines?
If I should keep it on, what should I do to avoid the error and to be sure that the build won't be affected by any weird issue with the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to disable the build cache.
If you can't do it because it is under source control and shared on several environments, I'd go with a little batch script that creates a copy of gradle.properties before the build, modify the original to disable the cache while building and in a post build step copy the unmodified original back to the location.
If everything is done right, this gradle.properties file will not be recognized as modified and will therefore not cause any pull/checkout conflicts.

I do this in several builds with more than one file (in c# we replace version numbers in the AssemblyInfo.cs file while building and then restore them, and we also do some file-hiphop with android builds)

hope this helps,
cheers, Gris

Comment: do you see any issue in cleaning the cache instead?

Comment: Not a technical one, but why build up a cache (takes time) and clean it afterwards (takes even more time). I consider it more efficient to simply disable it at all instead of creating it just to wipe it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to keep the cache. Now I'm:

1) setting the build cache dir in the `gradle.property`

2) cleaning the cache every time by calling `gradlew cleanBuildCache`